# Shutdown remote linux server with PHP

Tags: php, linux, ssh

I have an always running Raspberry Pi with LAMP installed, and a second server with more horsepower. I want to be able to start up and shutdown the second server from a PHP page on the Raspberry Pi. My code on the Raspberry Pi page is:

```
<form action="" method="POST">
<input type="Submit" value="Wake Up" name="WOL_Submit">
<input type="Submit" value="Shutdown" name="WOL_shutdown">
</form>

<?php

if(isset($_POST['WOL_Submit']))
{
    exec('sudo etherwake AA:BB:CC:DD:EE:FF');
    echo "WOL Packet sent...";
}

if(isset($_POST['WOL_shutdown']))
{
    exec('ssh user@192.168.1.100 "sudo /sbin/shutdown -P 0"');
    echo "Shutdown sent...";
}

?>
```

I have set up SSH keys, so I dont need to enter a password when SSH'ing from the Pi to the second server, and this works fine if I SSH normally, using putty for instance.

On the second server I have also added the user to visudo with `user ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /sbin/shutdown`.

The Wake on LAN command from the webpage works fine and the second server boots up, but the shutdown command does not. I get the message 'Shutdown sent...' but the server does not shutdown. I have tried swapping the " and ' in the `exec('ssh user@192...` command, and also tried using `ssh -t`, but the server does not shutdown still.

Answer (score 0):

Try ssh -i /path/to/id_rsa user@192.... and make sure the key is chmod 600 and owned by www-data, or whatever user php is running as

Comment: Ran `sudo chown www-data:www-data id_rsa` as the php page is run as www-data - ran `echo exec('whoami')` to confirm. 

Updated the command in the script to `exec('ssh /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa user@192.168.1.100 "sudo /sbin/shutdown -P 0"')`. Still unable to shutdown the second server from the php page on the pi though.

Comment: use php system command to see the actual command output. for example  $last_line = system('ls', $retval);

// Printing additional info
echo '
</pre>
<hr />Last line of the output: ' . $last_line . '
<hr />Return value: ' . $retval;

Comment: Also, I don't see the "-i" flag in there.

Comment: Sorry, typo in the previous comment, definitely running `exec('ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa ...`. id_rsa is owned by www-data and permissions set to 600. When I ran `$last_line = (''ssh -i /home/pi/.ssh/id_rsa user@192.168.1.100 "sudo /sbin/shutdown -P now"', $retval)` and printed the values of $last_line and $retval, I got "Last line of the output: [blank] Return value: 255

Comment: I don't recognize the shutdown flags - try ```sudo /sbin/shutdown -h now```